# How do I add selected cells into a different DataGridView box

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer

[Move from available to selected on double click][1]

I have 2 datagridviews and I want to move a particular cell that a user has clicked on from one grid to the other.

I tried this

```
private void availableFacilList_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedMove = availableFacilList.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)selectedFacilList.Rows[0].Clone();
    row.Cells[0].Value = selectedMove;
    selectedFacilList.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Image attached on how it looks
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjWiX.png

Comment: A datagridview *displays* data, it doesn't contain it. If you want to change the displayed data, change the actual data container (DataTable, List<Whatever>) that the grid binds to

Comment: I dont want to change it I want to display the selected cell to the other gridview on the side on double click

Comment: Sounds like you want to copy the __values__ to cells in dgv1  and then remove them from dgv2? - What exactly happens when you run your code??

Comment: Yes exactly unable to add row throws as it throws a ArgumentOutOfRange Exception

Comment: Did you ever add the necessary columns to the right dgv? (it is not enough to have the cells in the row, there also must be (enough) columns in the dgv!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the posted code appears to work if the second grid had at least one column. I am confident this is why the index out of range exception is thrown on the line of code…

```
DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)selectedFacilList.Rows[0].Clone();
```

Since … `selectedFacilList.Rows[0]` … row zero (0) does not exist.

Using a `DataSource` to both grids may make things easier for you. In this case, if both grids used two different `DataTables` with the same schema, then all you would need to do is move the selected row (s) from one `DataTable` to the other and the grids will update automatically.

To start, we want to make two (2) data tables with the same schema. It will have a single `string` column and we will use these tables to move the selected row from one table to the other and vice versa.

Creating these tables and filling one with some test data for the grid on the left may look similar to what your picture shows with the exception that the grid on the right has at least one column.

```
DataTable AvailableDT;
DataTable SelectedDT;

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  AvailableDT = GetEmptyDT();
  SelectedDT = GetEmptyDT();
  FillTableWithData(AvailableDT);
  availableFacilGrid.DataSource = AvailableDT;
  selectedFacilGrid.DataSource = SelectedDT;
}

private DataTable GetEmptyDT() {
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("Group", typeof(string));
  return dt;
}

private void FillTableWithData(DataTable dt) {
  dt.Rows.Add("Max Group of Hospitals");
  dt.Rows.Add("Fortis Group of Hospitals");
  dt.Rows.Add("Manipal Group of Hospitals");
  dt.Rows.Add("Appolo Group of Hospitals");
}
```

Next we need to subscribe to each grid’s `CellDoubleClick` event to move the rows back and forth. To simplify things, instead of writing code to move the row from the left to right and more code to move the row from right to left…  we write one method that can accommodate both moves.

In this method, we will need to know which “Grid” is the “source” grid so we can get the current selected cell from it. From that passed in grid we can get its `DataSource` `DataTable` so we can remove the selected row. The only other thing we need is the destination grids data source to add the row to. These two items are passed into the `MoveRow` method. This should simplify moving the rows either way and may look something like below…

```
private void MoveRow(DataGridView sourceGrid, DataTable destDT) {
  int sourceRowIndex = sourceGrid.CurrentRow.Index;
  if (sourceRowIndex >= 0 && !sourceGrid.Rows[sourceRowIndex].IsNewRow) {
    DataRowView selectedRow = (DataRowView)sourceGrid.Rows[sourceRowIndex].DataBoundItem;
    destDT.ImportRow(selectedRow.Row);
    ((DataTable)sourceGrid.DataSource).Rows.Remove(selectedRow.Row);
  }
}
```

The above code is straight forward… first we get the row index of the source grid’s `CurrentRow`. This is the row we want to move to the destination grid’s data source. Some bounds checking is made in addition to checking if the row is the grids `NewRow` in which case we do not want to move that row. If the checks are passed, then we grab the row from the grid with the line of code…

```
DataRowView selectedRow = (DataRowView)sourceGrid.Rows[sourceRowIndex].DataBoundItem;
```

This will get the row from the grids `DataSource`. You may note that when the code sets the `sourceRowIndex` variable with … `int sourceRowIndex = sourceGrid.CurrentRow.Index;` … this is the row index in relation to the GRID ROWS… and you may be tempted to get the row from the grids `DataSource` using THAT index with something like…

```
DataRowView selectedRow = sourceDT.Rows[sourceRowIndex];
```

This may work and it may not work. If the grid is NOT sorted or filtered, then there is a good chance that there IS a one-to-one correspondence to the row index in the gird and the row index in the grids underlying `DataTable`. However, if the grid is sorted or filtered, then this one-to-one correspondence is lost. In other words, the row at grid row index 3, may not necessarily be at row index 3 in the underlying data sources `DataTable`.

To ensure we get the “right” row from the grids data source, each grid Row has a `DataBoundItem` property that will give us the `DataRowView` of the corresponding `DataRow` in the `DataTable`. The code above shows this and it makes it much easier to add and remove that row from the table.

After we have the `DataRowView` of the source `DataTable` it is trivial to “import” the row from the `sourceDT` table to the destination `destDT` table. Then remove the row from the `sourceDT` table. Note, you will get an error if you attempt to simply “Add” the row from the source to the destination table. In other words… instead of using the import code like…

```
 destDT.ImportRow(selectedRow.Row);
```

We simply added the row like…

```
destDT.Rows.Add(selectedRow.Row);
```

The error will complain that you can not add a row to a table that already belongs to another table. Even if you “remove” the row from the source table before trying to add it to the destination table… you will still get the error. I am betting the row is still there but simply marked for deletion.

Fortunately, using the `DataTables` `ImportRow` avoids this and helps us “copy” the row. So given the `MoveRow` method above, it should simplify the code in both grids `CellDoubleClick` events and may look something like…

```
private void availableFacilGrid_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
  MoveRow(availableFacilGrid, SelectedDT);
}

private void selectedFacilGrid_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
  MoveRow(selectedFacilGrid, AvailableDT);
}
```

I hope this helps and makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rough implementation of your problem. Use the code as a base as it contains the basic logic and adapt it to your variables and event handlers. Happy coding!

```
DataTable DTAvailable, DTSelected;
internal void SetupGrid(Grid _grid, string _columnName)
{ //Add the columns  for the _grid object with the name _columnName}

internal void DoGridsLoad()
{ 
  DTSelected = LoadData();
  SetupGrid(Grid1, "Selected"); 
  Grid1.DataSource = DTAvailable;
  
  SetupGrid(Grid2, "Available");
  DTSelected = new DataTable();
  Grid2.DataSource = DTSelected;

}

internal void MoveToSelected(object sender, EventArgs e) //BTN Move to Selected
{ 
  DataRow toMove = DTAvailable[Grid1.CurrentRowIndex]; //locate Row
  DTSelected.Rows.Add(toMove);
  DTAvailable.Rows.Remove(toMove);
}

internal void MoveToAvailable(object sender, EventArgs e) //BTN Move to Available
{ 
  DataRow toMove = DTSelected[Grid2.CurrentRowIndex]; //locate Row
  DTAvailable.Rows.Add(toMove);
  DTSelected.Rows.Remove(toMove);
}
```